# How to make textbox as mandatory field in vb script

Tags: vbscript

I wanted to make some Textboxes and MaskedTextbox as mandatory fields in my Vb script.?

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: VB.Net has nothing to do with VBScript.

Comment: entity.SetFieldRequirednessForCurrentAction field_name ..?

Answer (score 0):

If it were me there are 2 ways to achieve this.

1) do it with Javascript - though this has the limiting factor that if javascript is turned of it is not a reliable means to ensure valid data.

```
<script language="JavaScript"><!--


function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("First name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
//-->
</script>

<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

2) Or do it natively with VBscript. E.g. at point of submiting data check to see if data is populated e.g.

```
<%

if proc="formSubmited" then

str_fname = request.form("fname")

if str_fname <> "" then

'do stuff
'response.redirect etc....

else
' continue showing page and dont redirect
' and maybe show some nice error flags next to edit boxes
str_fname_errorFlag = "* Error"
end if
end if
%>

<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp?proc=formSubmited" method="post">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><%=str_fname_errorFlag%>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```